# How to remove decimal point from string using pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading an xls file and converting to csv file in databricks using pyspark.
My input data is of string format 101101114501700 in the xls file. But after converting it to CSV format using pandas and writing to the datalake folder my data is showing as 101101114501700.0. My code is given below. Please help me why am I getting the decimal part in the data.

```
for file in os.listdir("/path/to/file"):
     if file.endswith(".xls"):
       filepath = os.path.join("/path/to/file",file)         
       filepath_pd = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)
       names = filepath_pd.sheet_names        
       df = pd.concat([filepath_pd.parse(name) for name in names])        
       df1 = df.to_csv("/path/to/file"+file.split('.')[0]+".csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
       print(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ": XLS files converted to CSV and moved to folder"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with Spark or PySpark. It's related to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

This is because Pandas interpret and infer columns' data type automatically. Since all the values of your column are numeric, Pandas will consider it as `float` data type.

To avoid this, [`pandas.ExcelFile.parse`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html#pandas.ExcelFile.parse) method accepts an argument called `converters`, you could use this to tell Pandas the specific column data type by:

```
# if you want one specific column as string
df = pd.concat([filepath_pd.parse(name, converters={'column_name': str}) for name in names])
```

OR

```
# if you want all columns as string
# and you have multi sheets and they do not have same columns
# this merge all sheets into one dataframe
def get_converters(excel_file, sheet_name, dt_cols):
    cols = excel_file.parse(sheet_name).columns
    converters = {col: str for col in cols if col not in dt_cols}
    for col in dt_cols:
        converters[col] = pd.to_datetime
    return converters

df = pd.concat([filepath_pd.parse(name, converters=get_converters(filepath_pd, name, ['date_column'])) for name in names]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

OR

```
# if you want all columns as string
# and all your sheets have same columns
cols = filepath_pd.parse().columns
dt_cols = ['date_column']
converters = {col: str for col in cols if col not in dt_cols}
for col in dt_cols:
    converters[col] = pd.to_datetime
df = pd.concat([filepath_pd.parse(name, converters=converters) for name in names]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Yuan for your reply. I have tried your solution but apparently dtype is not supported with Python engine. Any other solution you may have please share .Many thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Yuan, for one column it is working fine.If for multiple columns then how to make it as generic?

Comment: I updated the answer, it unions all your sheets into one `dataframe` and converts all columns of all sheets into `string`

Comment: Thanks Yuan, it works good for number columns but for date(2019-03-19) data it is appending like this 2019-03-19 00:00:00. Can you please let me know why this is causing ?
And can we do the same thing using read_excel is it possible with this one

Comment: Your date string problem is because Pandas converts automatically date columns into [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) type, when you apply converters (which apply `str()` on it), the default string representation `__str__()` of `pandas.Timestamp` is of format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, which is shown in your data.

Comment: Indeed you can do `pd.read_excel`, it's the same as `pd.ExcelFile.parse`

Comment: Thanks Yuan, for quick response.I have tried below code(after this comment) using read_excel,but still i'm getting the date(2019-03-19) data as 2019-03-19 00:00:00.can you please help me on this?

Comment: import pandas as pd 
import os
path="/dbfs/ab/TEST_B/"
path2="/dbfs/bc/TEST_B/CSV/"
for file inos.listdir( path ):
 if file.endswith(".xls"): 
filepath=os.path.join(path,file)
column_list = []
df_column = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheetname=0).columns
 for i in df_column 
column_list.append(i)
converter = {col: str for col in column_list} 
df_actual = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheetname=0,converters=converter)
df1=df_actual.to_csv(path2+file.split('.')[0]+"_read_excel_"+".csv", sep=',',index=False)

Comment: updated my answer, I added the timestamp consideration into `converters`

Comment: Thanks Yuan, but i need that date fields to be date type only not timestamp. the format is 2019-03-19 but i'm getting this 2019-03-19 00:00:00 .I need 2019-03-19 as date format

Comment: have you tried my up-to-date answer? it gives 2019-03-19 on my side.

Comment: You should ask another question on SO if you can't find any solution to it. I will answer there if I see it.

Comment: Also, if any answer under this question helped you, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thanks Yuan, I have tried as per your changes in code.Now i'm getting the correct date format.but when i'm trying to read the csv file after converting from xls to csv the date field format is showing as timestamp but when i check in the datalake i can see dateformat. Can you please help on this issue?
Sure will vote up.

Comment: You should ask another SO question. I've tried `df.to_csv` and then `pd.read_csv`, it gives me the right date format (like 2019-03-19)

Answer (score 2):

I think the field is automatically parsed as float when reading the excel. I would correct it afterwards:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(int)
```

If your column contains Nulls you can´t convert to integer so you will need to fill nulls first:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Then you can concatenate and store the way you were doing it

Comment: Thanks gigorio for your reply.But i need that  column to be in string because after converting to csv i'm doing substr for some columns.Can i have alternate solution using read_excel one?

Comment: df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)